# I am facing a problem in java that comparison between integer and character is not supported...Here I am attaching my coding.. please answer me

Tags: java

Here is my code. I have make a prepared statement but it is not working and error is showing

```
 String get;
 get=jtf1.getText();
 PreparedStatement ps = c.prepareStatement("DELETE FROM APP.RECORD WHERE ID = '"+get+"'");

 ps.setString(1, get);
 ps.execute();

 JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Successfully deleted ");


 java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Comparisons between 'INTEGER' and
 'CHAR (UCS_BASIC)' are not supported. Types must be comparable. String
 types must also have matching collation. If collation does not match,
 a possible solution is to cast operands to force them to the default
 collation (e.g. SELECT tablename FROM sys.systables WHERE
 CAST(tablename AS VARCHAR(128)) = 'T1')
```

Comment: Did you read the error message? It tells you exactly what is wrong with the code.

Comment: Plus the way you construct the `PreparedStatement` is just wrong. You can't be doing string concatenation there.